# Python 3.4.3 - Error Pyshark capture.sniff()

Tags: python-3.x, import, pyshark

Here is my code:

```
import pyshark
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
capture.sniff()
```

Now here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
capture.sniff()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 109, in load_packets
self.apply_on_packets(keep_packet, timeout=timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 201, in apply_on_packets
return self.eventloop.run_until_complete(coro)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/trollius/base_events.py", line 350, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/trollius/futures.py", line 286, in result
raise self._exception
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/trollius/tasks.py", line 250, in _step
result = coro.throw(exc)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 212, in packets_from_tshark
tshark_process = yield  From(self._get_tshark_process(packet_count=packet_count))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/trollius/tasks.py", line 252, in _step
result = coro.send(value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 298, in _get_tshark_process
parameters = [get_tshark_path(self.tshark_path), '-l', '-n', '-T', xml_type] + self.get_parameters(packet_count=packet_count)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyshark/tshark/tshark.py", line 93, in get_tshark_path
'Search these paths: {}'.format(possible_paths)
pyshark.tshark.tshark.TSharkNotFoundException: TShark not found. Try adding its location to the configuration file. Search these paths: ['C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe', '/usr/bin/tshark', '/bin/tshark', '/usr/sbin/tshark', '/sbin/tshark']
```

I am running mac os 10.10.x with python 3.4.3
Installed pyshark with `sudo pip3 install pyshark`

Answer (score 7):

Try Installing tshark that worked for me and I am on  Ubuntu linux.

```
sudo apt-get install TShark
```

Blessings.

Comment: I'm on mac :p (it is written in the description). Thanks anyways!

Comment: Thank you very much for this Linux solution !! made my day :)

Comment: For me it was `sudo apt-get install tshark` (case-sensitive).